# What is the best way to have a Google Spreadsheets script trigger once per year?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Say I want a script to trigger on the 1st of January every year.

It appears that Google Spreadsheets does not have a way to do this using time-driven triggers.
Here are some ways I have thought of doing this:

*-Setup a specific date and time trigger for each year.*

*-Have a script that triggers on the first of each month and increments a cell by 1, if the cell is a multiple of 12 then trigger the rest of the script.*

*-Have a script that triggers on the first of each month to check if it is January.*

I think the third option is the best but it still seems like bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no function in app script currently for year based trigger
but you can do this way,
  Schedules for January 1st, 2017

```
 var year = 2017; //get current year dynamically
```

check year, if changes reset your trigger with new year value.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
   .timeBased()
   .atDate(year, 1, 1)
   .create();
```

Comment: Sure, but that only works for one specific year, you can do the same thing using time driven triggers for specific dates. Say I want it to trigger every year for the next 1000 years, then it wouldn't work very well.